# Hardware-Incompatible SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, hardware-failure

I own an older 120gb INTEL 320-Series SSD. I have downloaded the SSD Toolbox, and have ensured that the drive has the most recent firmware.

Here's what's weird:

When I insert the drive into my HP Pavilion g7 laptop, it runs fine, is able to boot into Windows 7.

When I try this on my new desktop pc (2013), which has an MSI 7641 mainboard, it gets to the windows loading screen and BSODs (only for a flash, after that it shuts down, so I wasn't able to save the BSOD message). The same applies when I try it with an older HP Desktop (2008) I own, for which I don't have the specs.

When I boot into a different OS and connect it via a SATA-USB interface to any computer, or even just via plain SATA, I can use it fine, like an external ssd.

I'll be installing Linux Mint on it checking out whether it's able to boot into that.

Any tips on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows in general dosen't like changing hardware - I'd guess the original OS install was similar enough to the g7 so it would boot, but not the MSI 7641 (which uses an AMD processor) or your HP system. With a fresh install of windows, it should work fine. I'd try backing up and wiping the drive to be sure, if its causing a BSOD of an install thats not on the drive,

Comment: You may be right - I had no problem booting the windows drive on my thinkpad either, which also had an intel processor.

Comment: Honestly, the fact that it boots, without sysprep --generalize suprises me more than the BSODs